# Anti-spark for converter?

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistance, amperage

I have an ebike which I installed some cheap lights on just so it's legal for the time being.

I have received the components to make a light that works off of the main battery. The issue I am having is when I try to plug in the 35-60V to 12V converter, there is an initial spark.

The battery mount doesn't have anti-spark connectors and I don't think I could modify it to have that. Reading on the internet I found out that using an inductor would cause unwanted voltage fluctuations.

I am trying to think of a way to make a timed resistor system whereby when the bike's battery is plugged in only 5 amperes can flow through the converter circuit before the resistance is taken away.

I don't know if that's possible and I would just like to hear about some possible solutions.

Comment: "there are sparks" - is that a euphemism for something? Maybe you can try to be more explicit about the symptoms like, yes there's an initial spark but the lights then work fine or, I get a total meltdown of the wiring or maybe something else?

Comment: Just an initial spark

Comment: So, what's the problem then? An initial spark isn't a problem.

Comment: Sounds like a "soft-start 12V converter" is desired.

Comment: @Andyaka So is this not a very big deal?

Comment: It's not usually a big deal but it's somewhat preferred if you make "the connection" first and then activate the LEDs.